# Computer : $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\arctan~^{2} \left (\frac{1}{2n}\right)$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, closed-form

Today I have an arctan sum but I don't know if has a closed form :

$$\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\arctan~^{2} \left (\frac{1}{2n}\right)$$

Wolfram alpha give [see her.](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+%28arctan+%281%2F%282+k%29%29%29%5E2+from+k+%3D+1+to+%2B+%5C%5BInfinity%5D)
$$\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \text{arctan}~^{2} \left (\frac{1}{2n}\right) ≈ 0.372905$$
I don't have any ideas to start with this amazing summation
I'm happy to see your work!

---

Thanks!

Comment: I highly doubt this has any reasonable closed forms.

Comment: Hint: to get an idea of the approximation, arctan(x) asymptotically approaches x as $x\rightarrow 0$

Comment: Could you please give a bit of context... Why are you interested in this?

Comment: I'm struggling to imagine a context in which one can square an angle.

Comment: Dear Ellen.  You've been here far long enough to know not to ask such "I have no clue" questions.  Please edit your post, and if you need a reminder, please read [How to ask a good question](

Comment: @CalumGilhooley Good point.

Comment: $$
-\int_{1}^{\infty}\int_{1}^{\infty}
\frac{\pi  y \coth \left(\frac{\pi }{2 x}\right)-\pi  x \coth \left(\frac{\pi }{2 y}\right)}{4 x^3 y-4 x y^3}
\,\mathrm{d}x\,\mathrm{d}y
$$

Comment: I've seen a simple closed form for $$\sum \arctan\left(\frac{1}{2n^2}\right)$$ Closed form for this, if it exists, would look like something B. Gosper would come up with.